# PostGIS. Find intersection of a polygon from 2 points

Tags: postgis

I have 2 polygons and 2 points stored in postgres tables and Im trying to find the front and back of one of the the polygons (green dots) based on a line from the 2 red dots.

I'm trying to find the green dot that is intersected by the line between the 2 red dots.

```
select
    st_astext(ST_Intersection(p.poly_geog,st_makeline(st_makepoint( c1.longitude, c1.latitude),
                            st_makepoint( c2.longitude,c2.latitude))))
from
    polygonfence p
join index i on
    p.index_id = i.id
join coordinate c1 on
    i.start_coordinate_id = c1.id
join coordinate c2 on
    i.centre_coordinate_id = c2.id
```

[image]

Comment: You need to ask one question per question, but at the moment you seem to have two.    Can you also explain what you mean by front and back, I see the dots, but front and back don't spring to mind to describe them.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your question to focus on your most pressing issue.

Comment: Thanks. Ive eddited my question to only have one now and once I get it resolved I will open a second question If im still struggling. 

 I want to find the location of the green dot where the lines intersect but in not getting a point from my query Im getting a line string

Comment: Try : `(ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(p.poly_geog, st_makeline(st_makepoint(c1.longitude, c1.latitude), st_makepoint( c2.longitude, c2.latitude))))).geom`

Comment: No its giving me an error 

 `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function st_dump(geography) does not exist`  

Ive tried casting to ::geometry as well but its the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ST_Intersection function was returning a linestring for all of the line that fell within the polygon. Adding some explicit typecasts and ST_StartPoint returned the point i was looking for

```
(st_astext(ST_StartPoint((ST_Intersection(p.poly_geog::geometry, st_makeline(st_makepoint(c1.longitude, c1.latitude)::geography::geometry, st_makepoint( c2.longitude, c2.latitude)::geography::geometry))))))
```

Comment: You should apply `ST_Boundary(your_polygon_geom)` on your polygon geometry before using `ST_Intersection()`. So you will obtain the right point and not a line.